# Calling Viewbag Data from controller to view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

> Controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EmailScheduler()
        {
            long lCustDesignID = 1;
                int countProduct = gateWay.TotalCountOfCustomers(lCustDesignID);
                ViewBag.ItemCount = countProduct;

            return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

> View:-

```
<h4>Number Of Records - <span>@ViewBag.ItemCount</span> </h4>
```

> This controller is called on button click.
>
> From Controller how to get value to View in viewbag.

.

Comment: Is `EmailScheduler` ajax call?

Comment: yes it is ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `EmailScheduler` is ajax call then you cannot use `ViewBag` like you have tried.

You need to modify your code like below.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EmailScheduler()
{
   long lCustDesignID = 1;
   int countProduct = gateWay.TotalCountOfCustomers(lCustDesignID);                    
   return Json(countProduct,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Html**

```
<h4>Number Of Records - <span id="spnCount"></span> </h4>
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
   //....
   success: function(data){
      $('#spnCount').text(data);
   }
})
```

Comment: @RookieCoder Once check `data` in console

Comment: Object
Customers
:
Array(5)
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
length
:
5 IN console log

Comment: @RookieCoder You are returing `countProduct` from `EmailScheduler` method then how can it shows an array

Comment: coz in return Json there in Viewdata object

Comment: @RookieCoder than you need to select your particular object data from ajax success  response `data`.